# Не могу понять как передать данные через ajax в php

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

```html
<div class="zone-of-checkout container">
  <div class="col-md-9 send-email-class" style="padding-left: 0px;">
    <div class="outer-check-list">
      <div class="title-of-client">
        <span class="order-title-span">Данные покупателя:</span>
      </div>
      <form id="form-data-order" class="form-of-checkout">
        <div class="span-zone-checkout">
          <span class="bx-authform-starrequired">*</span><span> Ф.И.О.</span>
        </div>

        <input required type="text" name="name">
        <div class="span-zone-checkout">
          <span class="bx-authform-starrequired">*</span><span> E-Mail</span>
        </div>
        <input required type="email" name="email">
        <div class="span-zone-checkout">
          <span class="bx-authform-starrequired">*</span><span> Телефон</span>
        </div>
        <input required type="telephone" name="telephone">
        <div class="span-zone-checkout">
          <span class="bx-authform-starrequired">*</span><span> Адрес доставки</span>
        </div>
        <textarea required name="address"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="outer-check-list outer-check-list-product" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <div class="title-of-client">
        <span class="order_in">Товары в заказе:</span>
        <a href="checkout.php" class="change_order">Изменить: </a>
      </div>
      <div class="form-of-checkout form-of-checkout-orders">
        <!--<div class="line-order"> ВОТ ТУТ ЗАПОЛНЯЮТСЯ ТОВАРЫ ИЗ LOCAL STORAGE
     <div class="img-order-info">
      <a href="#" class="img-order-info-block">
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="img-order-info-text">
       Лучший сыр
      </a>
     </div>
     <div class="count-summ-order-info">
      <span class="count-order-info">
       9 шт
      </span>
      <span class="summ-order-info">
       25 722 тенге
      </span>
     </div>
    </div>!-->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="final-info-summ-checkout">
      <div class="line-one">
        <span style="font-weight: 800;">Товаров на: </span> <span class="itog-info">0 тенге</span>
      </div>

      <div class="line-two" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <span>Итого: </span><br><span class="itog-info" style="font-size: 27px; margin-top: 10px;">0 тенге</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Все приветствую надеюсь на получение помощи, проблема вот в чем, имеется форма
и контейнер, данные с которых надо передать в php и там как то распарсить.
Как просто сериализовать данные с формы и отправить в Php я знаю. А вот, как
дополнительно отправить еще и нужные данные (названия сыров, количество для каждого, сумма)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form-data-order").submit(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();
      //console.log($(".send-email-class").innerHTML);

      // check if the input is valid

      var data = $('#form-data-order').serializeArray();


      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "send-data-to-our-email.php",
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) { //Данные отправлены успешно
          console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(response) { // Данные не отправлены

        }
      });
    })
  })
</script>
```

с контейнера не понятно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Нужно отправить названия количество и цену всех товаров]

Comment: изложите свои знания в виде кода. а то мы вот не знаем, что вы знаете, а что нет, поэтому ответа на вопрос вам и не даст никто. тем более не понятно, что у вас относится к форме, а что к дополнительным данным.

Comment: В двух словах - данные собираются (либо через форму `<form></form>` либо просто на js извлекаются с полей и т.п..), создаётся "переменная" со всеми необходимыми данными и через ajax они отправляются (обычно, методом `post`) на сервер, который их считывает (на php через тот же `$_POST`) и дальше проводит с ними какие-то манипуляции

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду с "нужные данные с контейнера"? Данные не входящие в форму? Что должны нам сказать приведённые Вами скриншоты?

Comment: исправил описание проблемы, названия сыров их кол-во и сумма за каждый (это доплнительная информация из контейнера)

Comment: код бы посмотреть. Ну вообще обычно используется массив с названием data. Ну так вот и добавить в него элементы, которые вам нужны. Ну грубо говоря data['product'] = $('#your_div').text() или в таком духе

Comment: Названия сыров откуда берутся?

Comment: Названия сыров выводятся в контейнер из Localstorage и формируют divы (количество которых зависит от количества товаров в заказе) внутри diva с этими товарами

Comment: что вы видите в инспекторе на вкладке `network`? Там должен быть ваш запрос. Сделайте скрин что внутри (какие данные шлются). Ну и кода `php` не хватает...малоли...может у вас именование не верное...ну и `html` хотя бы формы прикрепите

Comment: Если необходимые Вам данные находятся в localStorage, то почему нельзя их брать из localStorage и добавлять к создаваемому Вами объекту data, который Вы отправляете на сервер с помощью AJAX?
P.S.: поправьте отступы в приведённом коде.

Comment: Да отправка идет через Ajax, я поправил вид html

Comment: не знаю как правильно произвести это самое добавление к создаваемому объекту

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь в методе ajax в data можно передать и массив, т.е. вы можете написать data:{data1:data1,data2:data2}, где data1 будет то что вы собрали с формы, остальные поля собирайте дальше (data2 это я для примера написал именуйте как хотите, называться потом в массиве они будут как назовёте)